# Write JSON in a file in subpackage using Java in WIN7

Tags: java, json, filewriter

I have a Java class in a package called for example `com.project.test` and I want to write some JSON in a file called `Output.json` which is located in a subpackage called `com.project.test.sources`.

This is the code I have tried :

```
        String gsonGraphe = gson.toJson(graphe); /* This is the JSON code to write */
        File file = new File("sources/Output.json");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        bufferedWriter.write(gsonGraphe);
        bufferedWriter.close();
```

And it gives me this error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Specified access path not found
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.neo4j.test.auteurPays.AuteurPays.main(AuteurPays.java:145)
```

It gives me the same error when I try : `File file = new File("/sources/Output.json");` or `File file = new File("sources\\Output.json");` or `File file = new File("\\sources\\Output.json");`

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

PS : I am using Eclipse Luna under Windows 7.

Comment: Does `sources` directory exists?

Comment: @Pshemo yes I have it!

Comment: Print result of `System.out.println(new File("sources/Output.json").getAbsolutePath())` to check which directory precise your `file` describes and then make sure that it exists.

Comment: When I try `File file = new File("sources/Output.json");`it gives me `C:\Users\me\workspace\myProject\sources\Output.json`

Comment: OK, so if you are sure that `C:\Users\me\workspace\myProject\sources` directory exists (you actually visited it via explorer) then I am out of ideas for now :/

Comment: It actually works when I do `File file = new File("src/com/project/test/sources/Output.json");` but can it be easier to write using a relative path starting from th java class?

Comment: I am not sure if you want to write it to `src` since it contains code files `*.java` not compiled code which is placed probably in `bin` or `dest` depending on project configuration. Anyway can you explain why you want to place this file inside this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All relative paths (ones that don't start with a drive letter on windows or a slash on linux) are relative to the current working directory, from which the application will be executed. Usually (but this depends heavily on environment, IDE etc.), this is the project directory which contains a dir called "src", "src/main/java" or similar, which in turn is the root of all your sources (e.g. *.java files).

If you have a package called "com.project.test.sources", below this root there have to be the directories "com/project/test/sources". So if you want a file to be within that package, you would have to use a path like
`src/com/project/test/sources` (depending on your source root).

However, you might not want to put a file generated by your application within the codebase of the application itself (so not below "src"-dir), but in a different dir like "data" or similar, so you dont mix up sources and dynamically generated files.